# communicating state of a potentiometer with a second arduino board

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to get an arduino board to read the state of a potentiometer which is connected to a master arduino board, without connecting the potentiometer to the second board with physical cables

I have tried using Wire.write and Wire.read to just transfer the one value.

The master arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
const int dial = A0;
int reading = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(dial, INPUT);
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {
  reading = analogRead(dial);
  Wire.beginTransmission(9);
  Wire.write(reading);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

The slave arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
int reading = 0;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void receiveEvent(int bytes) {
  reading = Wire.read();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(reading);
}
```

When I read the Serial Monitor, the potentiometer or "reading" in the slave arduino limits at 255 (I don't know why) in 6 intervals (goes from 0 to 255, then drops to 0 and does that 6 times). I expect it to do the full range of the potentiometer to cap out at 1023.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ADC is 10bit and won’t fit in a byte. (`Wire.write(value)` sends value as a single byte). You need to send `reading` in 2 bytes. Here is how to make 2 bytes.

```cpp
byte data1 = highByte(reading);
byte data2 = lowByte(reading);
```

On receiving side, reconstruct an `int` this way.

```cpp
byte data1 = Wire.read();
byte data2 = Wire.read();
reading = int(data1) << 8 | data2;
```